# Es posible crear un solo instalador para dos aplicaciones?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

veran: tengo una aplicacion desarrollada en C#, y el cliente necesita que cada vez que alguien ingrese datos en una tabla, el sistema muestre una alerta(eso esta resuelto), cree un segundo proyecto solo para las alertas.
mi duda es si es posible crear un solo instalador para esas dos aplicaciones.
Aclaro que el sistema no estara abierto constantemente, el que si estara abierto constantemente es el de las alertas.

Comment: mmm.. el instalador instala lo que le digas.. si vas a mandar dos ejecutables, cual seria el problema? que estas usando para construir el instalador?

Comment: El Setup Project de Visual

Comment: tambien tendria que agregar la salida de ese segundo projecto?

Comment: supongo que si.. no use ultimamente ese instalador...

Comment: tienes razon, si era asi. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En la opción "2. Specify Application Data" -> Files puedes añadir todos los ficheros que quieras "manualmente", y puedes elegir ejecutables (ya sean de tu proyecto u externos), dll, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ten cuidado si lo agregas asi, y no como salida del proyecto, porque no se genera automáticamente.

Saludos